# Any good documentation on util_db in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for information on what util_db in snowflake is used for. The account came with the database. Cannot find good documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

UTIL_DB is part of the initial account setup and contains some sample File Formats to load data. This does not utilize any data storage so they do not incur storage charges for your account.

The account owner can drop the database if required.

Comment: Looks like this has list of all databases, roles etc. Is this like a metadata information on the account?